# XML Error with exporting table from polyline shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, xml

I am trying to export a selection from an attribute table to an output and am enountering the following error (currently working in South America, so it's in Spanish, but it just says there is an invalid character in the text).

[image]

Can anyone help with this? There doesn't seem to be an invalid characters and other similar tables export well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've assumed from some of the icons on the toolbar in the background that you are using ArcGIS for Desktop so have added a tag accordingly.  Will the same selection export to another shapefile/table OK?  If so, it suggests that the data may be the issue rather than the XML export.

Comment: Yes I believe it is the data. I suppose I'm after information as to what invalid characters would be that wouldn't work with an XML output?